# Sharepoint Instant Messaging

Tags: sharepoint

Is there a webpart that can easily be dropped into our Sharepoint that shows all company users online and with the ability to instant message them.  Currently everyone is using various IM clients and would like to see something integrated within our intranet: sharepoint

Comment: What kind of server are you using for corporate IM?

Comment: this isn't really a programming question.  You might look at the Office Communicator (or whatever it's called) that comes bundled with some of the commercial versions of SharePoint.  It allows for presence and integrates nicely with Outlook and different aspects of SharePoint.

Answer (score -1):

https://sharepointmessenger.codeplex.com/ I have been developing this. It might help you out.